# C - Using .h files

Tags: c, header

I'm in the process of learning C for a coursework assignment. One thing that confuses me is header files. I've tried to find some information regarding my question to no avail.

My question is, say I have 3 different .c files. The convention is (atleast from reading sources) - each .c file has it's own .h file, e.g. parser.c has parser.h, lexer.c has lexer.h, typechecker.c has typechecker.h (if we were making a compiler).

We then go on to add a statement:

```
#include "parser.h"
#include "typechecker.h"
```

in the lexer.c file, and do the same with the other .c files (changing the header files we include).

Instead of using that convention, is it okay to add all the prototypes for all 3 <s>classes</s> files into one header, say header.h, and just include that in all 3 <s>classes</s>? The problem with this is that the 3 classes will have prototypes of functions already included in this class, but I don't see this as a problem (I'm a beginner at C so I could be wrong).

Thanks.

Comment: 1. C does not have classes. 2. What you have proposed is functionally fine (assuming it's done correctly). But it doesn't mean it is the best way to do it. In fact it's likely not to be the best way. Because by including everything in one big header file it is likely that you will violate modularity principles in any real project (ie, keep non dependent parts seperate). But these are all just general principles. The best way to organise the code structure is highly dependent on the actual code and is also arguably subjective (and hence this question is not that suitable for Stackoverflow).

Comment: The real reason not to do that is, in a large project if you do it your build times will explode. One way to look at headers / compilation units is that they are like a divide and conquer approach to compiling all your code into one. If you don't actually divide, and every piece is actually including the entire world, then you don't get any savings, instead you just multiply the work that needs to be done. (It's more of a problem with C++ than with C though.)

Comment: Only include header files IF the contents of the header file are used in the source file.  AND always include the header file for the current source file.  I.E. if the source file is named lexor.c, then always include the lexor.h file but do not include other header files unless the contents of that other header file are being used in the current (lexor.c) file.

Comment: If the number of header files being include gets unwieldy,  can pre-compile the header files and just include the results of the pre-compiled header.  Then, with an appropriately written makefile, only those files that have been changed will cause a re-compile (and a link only occurs if some underlying source/header file was changed.   Most `make` utilities compare the datastamp between source and object files to determine if a file has changed.

Comment: @AlanAu I edited that. Still used to OO languages so thanks for pointing that out :P. All of these make sense - I appreciate the comments and feedback. Is the general "convention" I outlined earlier the best way to handle headers? What if we have 50 different files - thats 49 `#include "<file.h>"` statements in each file.

Comment: To add (cannot edit above comment), by best, I mean is it better than my proposed method? Can it result in things being less likely to "go wrong" for example? Is it seen as good or bad programming practice - or is this also a subjective question? (I'm talking about the general convention I outlined at the start of my OP here :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you suggest is permissible but not recommended. Having all prototypes in one header will cost you in terms of compilation and building. try to concentrate on "why header files are used?". if you get this answer you will refrain from adding everything in one header file. header files are meant for modularity to provide source files only those information which they need. Secondly in large projects you have to define "private" header files which are used internally by your code and are not visible to outer word. Ofcourse you will provide other users with header file in order to use your code. 
So It is not advisable to put all prototypes even in your start of learning. As starter, make one header file per source file.

EDIT

if your header1.h has function function1(), wherever(all source files) you use function1(), you will add header1.h

Comment: You say "...but recommended". You mean "...but (not) recommended." right? Thanks for the reply. If I make one header file per source (.c ? ) file, then do I include this header file in every other source file or only source files that will make use of it? (I believe it's the latter but would just like confirmation).

Comment: provided simple example in answer

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But it's recommended for every .c file regardless of whether the functions contained in the .c file will be used externally, I create a header file? What about the main method? Do I include that in a header file?

Comment: in case you are designing API then externally used function should be in one header which you will provide the end user. There is no need for main declarartion

Comment: Okay. Right now I have multiple header files (one for each source file), and wherever I am using external functions, I am including the header file relating to those functions in the source file which requires the use of those functions. Does that seem eligible?